# js libraries with fully cross-browser svg manipulation

Tags: svg, vml

I have an svg map which I'm looking to add javascript interactions to. In the past I've used RaphaelJS, which worked well. But I'm what alternatives there might be for svg manipulation with js?

One of the problems I don't like is that Raphael JS uses its own proprietary js objects instead of svg. Are there maybe some js libraries that are able to take svg directly and still support vml output where required?

Comment: I'm a fan of D3. http://d3js.org/